# How to use SHA256 during signing with OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, pkcs#7

I need to use sha256 instead of the default sha1. How to override the same?

```
pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign certificate, private_key, content 
signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7.write_smime pkcs7, content
pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt receiver_certificate, signed, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc")
encrypted_data = OpenSSL::PKCS7.write_smime pkcs7
```

This the code that I have tried, I have 2 things to be done. Need to override the signing algorithm and also the encryption algorithm. In the code I have mentioned `OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc")`, but that I not working, the encryption happening is aes-256-cbc.

Comment: Improve your question by editing it, rather than adding stuff in the comments - comments are ephemeral and don't handle code well

Comment: I believe the internal OpenSSL function is `PKCS7_bio_add_digest`. Its located in `<openssl src>/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_doit.c`.